# I am writing to the file with MPI on Fortran and while checking what was written I don't get the expected results

Tags: mpi

Each process is building some array and is writing this array in the "correct" place, using mpi_file_write_at(). 
After writing to the file I read from the same place and it is not what I wrote. The code is attached. I am just a beginner in MPI, so sorry if the question is not clever.

```
program output
use mpi
implicit none
integer :: ierr,i,proc_num,file,intsize
integer :: status(mpi_status_size)
integer,parameter :: count=10
integer,dimension(count) :: buf
integer,dimension(3*count) :: arr
integer(kind=mpi_offset_kind) :: disp
call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,proc_num,ierr)
do i=1,count
   buf(i) = proc_num*count+i
enddo
call mpi_file_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,'out.txt',mpi_mode_wronly+mpi_mode_create,mpi_info_null,file,ierr)
call mpi_type_size(mpi_integer,intsize,ierr)
disp = proc_num*count*intsize
call mpi_file_write_at(file,disp,buf,count,mpi_integer,status,ierr)
if (proc_num==0) then
   call mpi_file_read_at(file,0,arr,3*count,mpi_integer,status,ierr)
   write(*,*),arr
endif
call mpi_file_close(file,ierr)
call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program output
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mpi_mode_wronly` to open the file. As stated [here](http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/B673/node180.html), it corresponds to "write only". Consequently, `mpi_file_read_at()` is likely to fail. It can be checked by looking at the output parameter `ierr`.

Could you try the `mpi_mode_rdwr` flag ? This should enable both read and write operations.

Moreover, [`MPI_File_write_at()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_write_at.3.php) is a noncollective operation. So process 0 can call `mpi_file_read_at()` before process 1 exited `MPI_File_write_at()`. A `mpi_barrier()` can be added to prevent that. Take a look at http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node305.htm . It features various examples using `MPI_File_write_at()`. It is likely that additional calls to [`MPI_File_sync()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_File_sync.html) and [`MPI_File_set_view()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_set_view.3.php) are required as well.

Notice that the code you provided is equivalent to a call to the function [`MPI_Gather()`](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/).